# How to create three evenly spaced buttons on the action bar

Tags: android, android-layout

I am new to android development and I was wondering how can I can create three evenly spaced buttons on the action bar and make sure that they fill up the whole action bar.

The code I have written so far

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_groups"
        android:showAsAction="always"
        android:title="@string/action_groups" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_list_of_contacts"
        android:showAsAction="always"
        android:title="@string/action_listOfContacts"/>
    <item
         android:id="@+id/action_favourites"
         android:showAsAction="always"
         android:title="@string/action_favourites" />
</menu>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do it by using `setCustomView()`

this is the sample layout (sp.xml)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal"
 >

<Button 
android:layout_width="0dp"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_weight="1"
android:text="button1"
/>

<Button 
android:layout_width="0dp"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_weight="1"
android:text="button1"
/>
<Button 
android:layout_width="0dp"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_weight="1"
android:text="button1"
/>

</LinearLayout>
```

And in the activity after `setContentView` do this

`getActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(false);
        getActionBar().setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);
        getActionBar().setCustomView(R.layout.sp);`